# Group By and Filter

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below. Group by id and if count(item) > 1 then, filter the data which is equal to 65 or 66. If count(item) = 1, do nothing. Can we do this using analytic functions or what is the best way to achieve this?

```
+----+------+
| Id | Item |
+----+------+
|  1 |  65  |
+----+------+
|  1 |  66  |
+----+------+
|  1 |  01  |
+----+------+
|  2 |  93  |
+----+------+
|  3 |  11  |
+----+------+
|  3 |  12  |
+----+------+
```

Output:

```
+----+------+
| Id | Item |
+----+------+
|  1 |  65  |
+----+------+
|  1 |  66  |
+----+------+
|  2 |  93  |
+----+------+
```

Comment: What do you mean "starts with 65 or 66"?

Comment: Select id from table group by id having count(item)>1. And the results wil be joined with actual table to get only 65 and 64 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
select id, item
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1 and item in (65, 66) or cnt = 1;
```

If `item` is a string and you want the first two characters to be 65 or 66, then something like:

```
select id, item
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1 and regexp_like(item, '^(65|66)') or cnt = 1;
```

Comment: I think it should be `'^(65|66)'` for *first two characters* or better `substr(item, 1, 2) in ('65', '66')` but I see that OP has now removed the "start with" thing.

Comment: How will I modify if I have same ID and Item?. Say in the above example, id=1 and item=01 is repeated twice, should get only one

Comment: @Deek . . . Perhaps you should ask another question.  This question specifically excludes duplicates ("count(item) > 1").

Comment: Its the same question with extra condition. And hence asked

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
   r.Id,
   r.Item,
   t1.count
FROM
results r
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
      Id,
      Count(Id) as count
  FROM
    results
  GROUP BY Id
) t1 ON t1.Id = r.ID
WHERE r.Item IN (65, 66) OR t1.count = 1;
```